# IIS 8.0 Switch from Binary to W3C file format

Tags: iis

When I turn on logging on IIS 8.0 it starts write logs to binary file which has .ibl file extension.
I can't manage to switch log file format from binary to W3C, in other words from .ibl to .log extension. Would you please help me out with that.

Host and Site configuration is pretty straightforward:

[image]

[image]

This is how logs files look like:
[image]

Comment: When you set the format to W3C, did you click the apply under the Actions?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is found.

In order to fix that it's required to:

1. Stop IIS (net stop W3SVC)
2. Delete/rename C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC\
3. Start IIS (net start W3SVC)